# How to use 3rd party method that takes callback in "onComplete" hook in webdriverio

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

I need some help using a 3rd party method in `WebDriverIO`. I know that to use a 3rd Party method is necessary to encapsulate it in a Promise, which is called using `browser.call`.
The thing is that I need to call this 3rd party method in the `OnComplete` hook in the conf file, and there I don't have a browser object to use, so, my question is, what can I use there to call a promise?

I'm using `wdioRunner` with `sync:true` and also `Mocha` as the framework.

This is an example using browser.call :

```
browser.call(() => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      testrail.addResult(
        testCaseId,
        {
          status_id: statusTestCase,
          comment: `Automated Chrome Execution.
          Branch : ${runIdJson.branchName}
        },
        function(error, response, result) {
          console.log('Test Case status correctly Updated in TestRail');
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return reject(error);
          }
          return resolve(result);
        }
      );
    });
  });
```

And this is what I have now in the *OnComplete* hook :

```
onComplete() {
    browser.call(() => {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        testrail.getTests(content.runId, function(
          otherErr,
          responseTests,
          runTests
        ) {
          console.log(`Othererr : ${otherErr}`);
          console.log(`responseTests${responseTests}`);
          console.log(`RunTests: ${runTests}`);
          runTests.forEach(function(element) {
            console.log(`testCaseid ${testCaseId}`);
            if (element.case_id === content.testId) {
              testCaseId = element.id;
              if (
                content.result === 'failed' ||
                content.result === 'skipped'
              ) {
                statusTestCase = 5;
              } else if (content.result === 'passed') {
                statusTestCase = 1;
              }
            }
            if (otherErr) {
              return reject();
            }
            return resolve();
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

I'm getting this error, which is fine, because browser dosn't exists at this point.

> ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: Error in onCompleteHook: ReferenceError:
>   browser is not defined"

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Reference to `browser` object would be created and closed between `before` and `after` hooks. So here you are trying to make use of one the `browser` property(i.e., `call`) in the `onComplete` hook(which would not know what the `browser` means). That is the reason for error.

So coming to how to FIX your problem, the `onComplete` hook works just like any other JavaScript function. You should able to directly use the `callback` without wrapping it inside `browser.call`.

Something like this:

```
onComplete() {
        testrail.getTests(content.runId, function(othherErr, responseTests, runTests) {
          if(othherErr){
            console.log(`Othererr : ${otherErr}`);
          }
          console.log(`responseTests${responseTests}`);
          console.log(`RunTests: ${runTests}`);
          runTests.forEach(function(element) {
            console.log(`testCaseid ${testCaseId}`);
            if (element.case_id === content.testId) {
              testCaseId = element.id;
              if (
                content.result === 'failed' ||
                content.result === 'skipped'
              ) {
                statusTestCase = 5;
              } else if (content.result === 'passed') {
                statusTestCase = 1;
              }
            }
          });
    });
    }
```